# Debt on Credit Card problem

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus

> Emily has not always made the best decisions with her finances and is currently 11000USD in debt on her credit card. She decides to pay back 200 USD a month and make no further purchases on the card. The credit card company harges an APR of 23% that is compounded monthly.
>
> A)Find the fixed point of this recursive relationship.
> B)Will Emily ever be able to pay off her debt (justify by using part A)?

I had no problem finding the fixed point, which is $10434.78, but I don't see how I can answer B), especially by using A). The answer says no because the "debt is greater than the fixed point", but I don't understand this reasoning so can anyone explain this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The more debt Emily has, the less progress she is able to make paying it off per month, since she owes more interest each month.  The fixed point is exactly the point at which the 200 she pays back cancels out the interest she owes, so her balance remains constant.  If she has less debt than the fixed point, then the interest each month is less than what she pays back, so her debt decreases each month and she can eventually pay it off.  But if she has more debt than the fixed point, then she owes more in interest than she pays back each month.  That means each month she ends up owing more than she did the previous month, so her balance only gets worse and worse and she can never pay off the debt.

Answer (score 0):

A simple answer would be that if she owes $10434.78$ and the interest rate is $23$%, then on the first month she will owe $\frac{23%}{12}$%. The means that she owes $210.83$ the first month in interest only. If she pays only $200$ at the end of the month, she will now owe $more$ money than she did the month before. This pattern will continue forever (the interest owed on $10434.78 + 10$ is more than the interest on $10434.78$

P.S. APR is calculated as $23$/$12$% each month.